# IOS App Review Rejection Cordova based OBDX-18.3

Tags: ios, cordova

Tried to upload Oracle-OBDX-18.3 IOS app in app store,rejection email contains

***ITMS-90511***: CFBundleIdentifier Collision - The AppName-Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'org.apache.cordova.Cordova' of 'AppName.app/Frameworks/Cordova.framework' is already in use by another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the bundle identifier as per the custom package structure on info.plist of all the related frameworks provided in the installer. Like OBDXFramework.framework, Cordova.framework, OBDXExtensions.framework, OBDXWatchFramework.framework. Oracle has given the steps on configuring the under identifier on the respective frameworks, which was mentioned on the iOS configuration document of version 18.3. Please verify the oracle documentation link for your better understanding.
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509413/cordova-ios-app-failed-to-load-image-from-url